# Late 2010 MacBook Pro start issue

Tags: macbook-pro

After an errant update to OSX 10.6.7 my MacBook Pro stalls at ethernet configuration with a

"Ethernet [AppleBCM5701Ethernet]: Link up on en0, 1 Gigabit, Full-duplex, Symmetric flow-control, Debug [796d,0f01,0de1,0300,cde1,3c00]

DSMOS has arrived"

That's where it ends. There is a ethernet cable attached when I get this message. When booting with it unplugged I get a stall after the bluetooth initialization which is traditionally a line before.

The system was working perfectly before the update, as I did a restore from a time machine backup.

The problem is that I don't have a system disc to boot from. My reseller gave me one for the wrong model and they are, "slightly less than available.."

Not quite sure where to go from here. I managed to boot from a USB sparsebundle image from my Brother's MBP, but don't know how to go about fixing the issue at hand as I can't install a 10.6.6 update on a 10.6.7 hard drive from a USB drive.

And now, obviously, I can't boot from the hard drive or know how to gain root access to attempt to fix things.

Am I screwed or do I need to slouch into a local reseller and have them fix things?

Thanks in advance.

PS: System specs: MBP 13" 2.66 C2D, July 2010, 8Gb, 1Tb.

Comment: FYI, *"DSMOS has arrived"* means that the boot process is **over**. I had a friend with a problem similar to this a few years ago and an Archive & Install fixed the problem.

Comment: @squricle Thanks for the info, everything helps.